# Cannot assign foreign key with item ID

Tags: python, django

I am trying to auto assign a value to a foreign key, so that the model is automatically associated with another model. This is done when an entry is made by a form. I get the following error

```
ValueError at /nodiso/createaction/23/
Cannot assign "'23'": "LeadActions.lead" must be a "Leads" instance.
```

**This is the two models:**

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=265)
    tel = models.IntegerField()
    dateenq = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('nodisoapp:leadlist')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class LeadActions(models.Model):
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Leads)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    crdate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    Duedate = models.DateField()
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    overdue = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)



    def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('nodisoapp:leadlist')

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

**This is the View**

```
class ActionCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    login_url = '/scrty/login/'
    template_name = "nodiso/actioncreate.html"
    form_class = forms.LeadActionCreateForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.lead = self.kwargs['pk']
        self.object.creator = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(LeadCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**This is the model form**

```
class LeadActionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LeadActions
        fields = ['name','Duedate']
```

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.object.lead_id = self.kwargs['pk']
```

Since you are using the key value directly, use need to reference the variable with '_id'.

Another way is:

```
self.object.lead_id = Lead.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Which in this case is not required, since you have the key value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
self.object.lead = self.kwargs['pk']
```

try doing

```
lead_id = int(self.kwargs['pk'])
self.object.lead = Lead.objects.get(pk=lead_id)
```

When using the field name to assign relationship fields in Django, you must pass a model instance not a primary key. You could also use the primary key by doing:

```
lead_id = int(self.kwargs['pk'])
self.object.lead_id = lead_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here.

One, you need to use the `lead_id` field name if you have the PK of the related instance rather than an instance object.

Two, kwargs matched from the URI regexp are strings, while PK values are integers. Assuming your uris regexp is properly restrictive, you can just convert it using `int`. So combining the two:

```
self.object.lead = int(self.kwargs['pk'])
```